# how to get dropdown(select box) all value and write in any div

Tags: jquery

i have dropdown(select) box Like :

```
<select name="drp_name" id="drp_name">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

i want get all option value and write(print) in any div like :

```
<div id="main_div">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward:

```
$('#drp_name option').map(function() {
    return $('<div />', {text: $(this).text()}).get(0); // or this.value / $(this).val()
}).appendTo('#main_div');
```

**Reference**: [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), [`.appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DnkzB/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#main_div').empty();
$('#drp_name option').each(function() {
  $('#main_div').append('<div>'+ $(this).text() +'</div>');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/PPhsn/1/)**

If your `div`s within `#main_div` are previously exists then

```
$('#drp_name option').each(function(index, item) {
  $('#main_div div').eq(index -1).html($(this).text());
});
```

or

```
$('#main_div').empty();
$('#drp_name option').filter(function() {
  $('#main_div').append('<div>'+ $(this).text() +'</div>');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/PPhsn/)**

**NOTE** If you need `value` then use `this.value`.

Comment: I'd say he wants the text, not the value - even though it's the same in this case.

Comment: @ThiefMaster. _"i want get all option **value**"_

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = $('#main_div').empty();
$('#drp_name > option').each(function() {
    $('<div/>').text($(this).text()).appendTo(div);
});
```

If you do not want the texts of the options but the values, replace `$(this).text()` with `this.value`.